# Activation context generation failed. VC Runtime Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime

There are two services that I am trying to install, both developed in c++. I get these error when I try and install them one for one :

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Timer.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.6161" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

For second service:

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Porc.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

I tried installing these two packages: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) and 
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11895)

but after clicking there `setup.exe` files the setup just closes and vanishes away itself after a while.

Another thing I believe above packages are for `8.0.50608.0` so do I need to install some other package `9.0.30729.6161` of is there one package that would be enough for both of them can you please help. I am using `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the word `Debug` in `Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT` and `Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT`. The public redistributables you linked to do not provide the DebugCRT, and they do not offer redistribution rights for them either. Thus if you are using this internally, you can use it on a machine with Visual Studio. If you need to test it on another machine, you will either need to install the DebugCRT there (Visual Studio includes a merge module, last I saw, but doesn't allow further redistribution), or to compile and the *Release* configuration of your project.